# How to easily understand and learn angular 8?

Tags: angular, angular-components, angular-module

I am a fresher and I am working in angular 8.It is little bit confusing for me because it has a lot of components and modules.Can u recommend how to learn angular 8 easily.

Comment: I mean, here it is: https://angular.io/start

Comment: YouTube course is your first step -- Good Luck mate. **Practice makes perfect**

Answer (score 4):

There are many sources on the web for small applications to learn how it works.
Like Eudz said, theres https://angular.io/start, but if you search for small tutorials like todo-list (which there are many of) [on google](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=angular%208%20todo) you can try and learn it from there.

There's no ultimate site to teach you everything in 1 hour. It's just trying new things and learning by doing